# jQuery Validation on a .form-group with multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Using [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin, I defined the following for my Bootstrap `form`:

```
$(".form-with-validation").validate({
    errorClass: "help-block",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

It works well for a simple form. However, the part with `highlight` and `unhighlight` doesn't work when a `.form-group` contains multiple inputs (inline) that need to be validated:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State &amp; Zip</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control required" name="state">
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="zip">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that once you select a state for example, the input becomes valid, and its `.form-group` parent **loses `.has-error` class**, even though the **sibling input** (i.e. zip) is **still invalid** (i.e. has a `.help-block` span below it):

[image]

So, I changed the `unhighlight` part to the following:

```
unhighlight: function(element) {
    var formGroup = $(element).closest('.form-group');
    var formGroupIsValid = true;
    formGroup.find('input').each(function(){
        if (! $(this).valid())
            formGroupIsValid = false;
    });
    if (formGroupIsValid)
        formGroup.removeClass('has-error');
}
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Any ideas why? I tried many approaches, but each time I get the same error.

#### EDIT

I'd prefer to stick with `div.form-group` having `.has-error` class if possible (because of styling).

#### EDIT 2

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5ufn4v4/3/) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up with. It was simpler than I thought. As people have indicated before, any `form-group` should contain only one `form-control` at a time. The easiest solution is thus to put a second `form-group` inside the first one and then place the second `form-control` in there:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State &amp; Zip</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control required" name="state">
                    ...
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group" style="margin-bottom:0;padding-right:0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="zip">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With just a few CSS styles, this works perfectly and looks just fine. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sccpyy20/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function which calls another function and so on, until you hit the call stack limit.  I am going to assume the problem is in your `.each` loop when you call `.valid()`.

You shouldn't have to do any of that though.  Instead of targeting `form-group` you should target something around the input specifically so you don't have to change that `unhightlight` function.  For example something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State &amp; Zip</label>
    <div class="col-md-3 inputToValidate">
        <select class="form-control required" name="state">
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 inputToValidate">
        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="zip">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then update the JavaScript code to something like:

```
$(".form-with-validation").validate({
    errorClass: "help-block",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.inputToValidate').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.inputToValidate').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to stick with `.form-group` since if I target the closest `div` for example, my CSS styling would be messed up. But thanks for your input nonetheless!

Comment: @Alex Oh I see, you still want the red to show on the label too? Or are you talking about other css?  You are still leaving form-group so other css should be intact.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd prefer to stick with div.form-group having .has-error class if possible

It's not possible with the options provided by the plugin.  The valid/invalid classes are toggled on the element being validated.  The `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions can be modified to toggle classes on other elements using jQuery DOM traversal, etc.

However, you want logic that makes a parent container "invalid" when any of its children are invalid... the plugin is not equipped for that.  As soon as an invalid child element triggers the error class on the parent, any valid child element will apply the valid class to the same parent.

A workaround would be an *external* `keyup` and `change` handler that looks at the classes on all sibling input elements and toggles its parent class accordingly.  Based on your own code and untested...

```
$('input, select').on('keyup change', function() {
    var formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
    var formGroupIsValid = true;
    formGroup.find('input, select').each(function(){
        if (! $(this).valid()) {
            formGroupIsValid = false;
        }
    });
    if (formGroupIsValid) {
        formGroup.removeClass('has-error');
    } else {
        formGroup.addClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

> I get the following error: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` .... Any ideas why?

Yes, you are calling the `.valid()` method from within the `.validate()` method (via `unhighlight`).  So calling `$(this).valid()` from within this method only causes `unhighlight` to be called again... and so on indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate response. Unfortunately, the workaround did not work for me... I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5ufn4v4/3/) to demonstrate this. Could you have a quick look at it please?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use the form-with-validation class you can target all the form field that you are wanting to validate by selecting the inputToValidate class. It also much simpler. Also you probably want to use the toggleClass.

```
$(".inputToValidaten").validate({
    errorClass: "help-block",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(this).toggleClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(this).toggleClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

**Updates and Edites**

OK. So here is code that will work on any nested form field with the form-control class. It will go up and grab the closest element with the form-group class and then add you validation code to it.

```
$(".form-control").validate({
    errorClass: "help-block",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(e) {
        $(e.target).closest('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(e) {
        $(e.target).closest('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to apply the error class to the ***parent*** if any one of its children is invalid... this is very different than what you're showing us.

Comment: And the way you've setup `.validate()` here with these options, you can only attach it to a single form element, not a class of inputs.  It just doesn't work like that.